# How to navigate through a linked list without using a for or while loop?

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to go through a linked list without using a for loop or while loop.

```
class VaccList:
    class Appointment:
        def __init__(self, name, age, city, date):
            assert type(name) is str, 'name variable must be a string'
            assert type(age) is int, 'age variable must be a integer'
            assert type(city) is str, 'city variable must be a string'
            assert type(date) is datetime, 'date variable must be a datetime object'
            assert name != None, 'name variable cannot be empty'
            assert age >= 18 and age <= 100, 'age must be between 18 and 100'
            #   ADD 6 asserts.  4 for the types and name cannot be empty, 
            #   and age must be between 18 and 100

            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.city = city
            self.date = date
            self.confirmed = False
            self.next = None

        def __str__(self):
            s = "Appointment for " + self.name + " on " + str(self.date) + " age:" + str(self.age) + "  city:" + self.city
            if self.confirmed:
                s += " (confirmed)"
            else:
                s += " (unconfirmed)"
            return s

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None


    def confirm(self, name):    
        '''
        Find an appointment for a person with the given name and set confirmed to true.
        Return a string message  "not found", "confirmed", "already confirmed."
    '''
        # Note... no loop!
        #  assert, type of name and non-empty string
        assert type(name) is str, 'name variable must be a string'
        assert name != None
        current = self.head
        if current.name == name:
            if current.confirmed == False:
                current.confirmed = True
                return 'confirmed'
            else:
                return 'already confirmed'
```

This is my method from a class I created and I am trying to confirm appointments unless they have already been confirmed. I can confirm the first appointment but if the name im searching for isnt the first name in the list of appointments, how would I get to the next name to check?

Comment: You can try using recursion

Comment: Why do you want to try to do this without a loop?  Are you able to use another data structure that doesn't need to be searched linearly?

Comment: @Samwise only doing this without a loop because its meant for a school project.

Comment: In order to answer this question, we will need to see at least the structure of the node in the linked list. Please [edit] your question and add this.

Comment: @martineau Just did, thanks for the advice

Comment: How do new appointments get added?  Are you allowed to modify that code?  (Add a dict!)

Comment: The other option (other than using a loop) is to use recursion, but that's a really bad solution for Python because of the lack of TCO (unlike most languages, if you use recursion on a long list in Python it'll grow the stack and crash your app instead of being optimized into a constant-space loop equivalent).

Comment: @Samwise: IMO the lack of Tail Call Optimization in Python is seldom a problem in the "real world" because most problems don't require enough recursive calls for it to be one.

Comment: ask me how I learned about Python's lack of TCO (it was in the real world, lol)

Comment: @Samwise: One edge case does not make saying "seldom" incorrect.

Comment: It's not an "edge" if you hit it for every iteration that's longer than 1000 elements.  :)  Quite a few real-world problems involve data sets that are much larger!  The only reason it's not often a problem in the real world is that most people simply don't do this terrible thing.  (I hit it because I needed to add a retry and did it the laziest way possible, assuming Python had TCO and it'd be same-same.)  If you try to replace all the loops in a real-world Python app with recursion (as this exercise is training the student to do) I think you're more likely than not to hit the stack limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to avoid a loop by doing things recursively as @user15270287 suggested early on. I had to add a `add_appt()` method to be able to add them to a list in order to be able to create one for testing the code, so your mileage may vary.

Other than that and the unit test at the end, all the changes were to the `confirm()` method.

```
from datetime import datetime


class VaccList:
    class Appointment:
        def __init__(self, name, age, city, date):
            assert type(name) is str, 'name variable must be a string'
            assert type(age) is int, 'age variable must be a integer'
            assert type(city) is str, 'city variable must be a string'
            assert type(date) is datetime, 'date variable must be a datetime object'
            assert name != None, 'name variable cannot be empty'
            assert age >= 18 and age <= 100, 'age must be between 18 and 100'
            #   ADD 6 asserts.  4 for the types and name cannot be empty,
            #   and age must be between 18 and 100

            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.city = city
            self.date = date
            self.confirmed = False
            self.next = None

        def __str__(self):
            s = ("Appointment for " + self.name + " on " + str(self.date) + " age:"
                    + str(self.age) + "  city:" + self.city)
            if self.confirmed:
                s += " (confirmed)"
            else:
                s += " (unconfirmed)"
            return s

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    # ADDED FOR TESTING PURPOSES.
    def add_appt(self, name, age, city, date):
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        new_appt = VaccList.Appointment(name, age, city, date)
        new_appt.next = self.head
        self.head = new_appt

    def confirm(self, name, start=None):
        '''
        Find an appointment for a person with the given name and set confirmed to true.
        Return a string message  "not found", "confirmed", "already confirmed."
        '''
        # Note... no loop!
        #  assert, type of name and non-empty string
        assert type(name) is str, 'name variable must be a string'
        assert name != None

        # Start at beginning of list unless different node is specified.
        current = self.head if start is None else start
        if current is None:
            return 'list is empty!'
        if current.name == name:
            if current.confirmed == False:
                current.confirmed = True
                return 'confirmed'
            else:
                return 'already confirmed'
        else:
            if current.next is None:  # End of list?
                return 'not found'
            return self.confirm(name, start=current.next)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    vlist = VaccList()
    vlist.add_appt('Bob', 25, 'Tacoma', '2021-03-21')
    vlist.add_appt('Sue', 31, 'Seattle', '2021-03-22')
    vlist.add_appt('Ted', 28, 'Auburn', '2021-03-23')

    result = vlist.confirm('Sue')
    print('Sue is {}'.format(result))
    result = vlist.confirm('Sue')
    print('Sue is now {}'.format(result))
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! I really appreciate it, I just wasn't sure how to use recursion and make it stop once it got to the last appointment.

Comment: Yes, being able to determine when/how to stop is a crucial aspect of using recursion, otherwise you'll exceed Python's maximum recursion limit (because of stackoverflow `;¬)`

Comment: Off-topic: BTW, nesting classes like that generally-speaking has few benefits in Python, and in fact often makes things awkward and more liable to break, so therefore is usually avoided.

Comment: Yeah, I have been told that from multiple people but my professor wanted it set up like this for some reason. I too prefer to use seperate classes.

Comment: The reason may be due to one of the few advantages of it there are, namely [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). However in a "real world" scenario, `VaccList` would be defined in a separate module, allowing `Appointment` to be made separate and still be considered to be "bundled".